# ggplot : label count and percent

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shinyapps

I have a chart that shows percentage as label. I would like to add next to the percentage, the count. Is it possible ?
Here's my code :

```
 output$sortie4 <- renderPlot ({
        ggplot(filtered_data3(), aes(x= LV1,  group=Cycle)) + 
            geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., fill = factor(..x..)), stat="count") +
            geom_text(aes( label = scales::percent(round(..prop.., 2)),
            y= ..prop.. ), stat= "count", vjust = -.5) +
            labs(y = "Percent", fill="LV1") +
            facet_grid(~Cycle) +
            guides(fill="none")+
            scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
            theme(text = element_text(size=17),
                  axis.text.x = element_text(angle=80, hjust=1))
        })
```

And here's my chart :
[image]

Here's a part of my dataframe :

```
data.frame(
  Cycle = c("Cycle 1", "Cycle 2", "Cycle 3", "Cycle 2", " Cycle 1"),
  LV1 = c("Anglais", "Anglais", "Pas de LV1", "Italien", "Anglais"),
  Number = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
)
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an extra sample in the dataset:

```
example = data.frame(
  Cycle = c("Cycle 1", "Cycle 2", "Cycle 3", "Cycle 2", " Cycle 1","Cycle 2"),
  LV1 = c("Anglais", "Anglais", "Pas de LV1", "Italien", "Anglais", "Anglais"),
  Number = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
)
```

Using `paste()` you can combine the outputs of the stat `..count..` and `..prop..` as the label for `geom_text()`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(example, aes(x= LV1,  group=Cycle)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., fill = factor(..x..)), stat="count") +
  geom_text(aes( label = paste( ..count..,
                                scales::percent(round(..prop.., 2)),
                                sep=" - "
                                ),
                 y= ..prop.. ), stat= "count", vjust = -.5) +
  labs(y = "Percent", fill="LV1") +
  facet_grid(~Cycle) +
  guides(fill="none")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
  theme(text = element_text(size=17),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=80, hjust=1))
```

You can edit the inputs, the order, the separator, ...,  in `geom_text(aes( label = paste(...) ) )` to adapt it to your expectations.

[image]